# How do I write two sentences in the same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to write this form of sentence,

```
text1                text2
```

in the same sentence in the first page of my report. I tried to use flushleft and I right, but I got every text in a different sentence, like this:

```
text1
                               text2
```

I used these instructions:

```
begin{flushleft}
\textbf{text1}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{text2}
\end{flushright}
\end{flushleft}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems that you like to have something like this `text1 \hfill text2` ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is not compilable.

Comment: Sentences or single words? If the former, can you give a more extensive example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this? (The `showframe` package is only to show the alignment, just remove it for production run)

The `flushleft` or `flushright` environments introduce some vertical spacing each time, this is cause for the two different lines!

Use `\hfill` for easy cases, or a tabular, for more complicated setups, (i.e. line wrapping etc., which is quite likely if 'sentences' are to be used instead of short words)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{text1}
\hfill
\textbf{text2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update, with some wrapping for sentences

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\sentenceleftright}[2]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}c@{}Y@{}}
    #1 & & #2\\
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\textbf{text1}
\hfill
\textbf{text2}
\sentenceleftright{left}{right}
\sentenceleftright{And now (at last but not least) for something}{really really really really completely different}

\end{document}
```

[image]