# \preauthor{\begin{flushright} Not align with \begin{flushleft}

Tags: horizontal-alignment

For my cover i need to have the right part of the text aligned with the left part, but it's not happening, Here i link my code and the image can you please help me out?

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 

\input{structure.tex} 

%------------------------------------------------
% Thesis Information

\title{Un Modello per la Rappresentazione della Semantica di Diagnosi Cliniche \Large \newline \newline \centerline{Tesi in} \newline Data Management} 

\author{Luigi Vecchione} 

\date{18 Luglio 2016} 

\newcommand{\institution}{University degli Studi di Salerno\xspace} 

\newcommand{\department}{\centerline{Dipartimento di} \newline Scienze Aziendali - Management \& Innovation Systems\xspace} 

%------------------------------------------------
% Fonts

\renewcommand*{\acffont}[1]{{\normalsize\itshape #1}} 
\renewcommand*{\acfsfont}[1]{{\normalsize\upshape #1}} 

%------------------------------------------------
% Hyphenations

\hyphenation{a-no-ma-lous a-no-ma-ly amounts breaches} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Figures/logounisa}\\[.5cm] 
\institution\\ 
\emph{\department}\\[.2cm] 
Laurea Magistrale in Tecnologie Informatiche e Management 
\par
\hrulefill
\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
Relatore:\\
\textbf{Prof. Giuseppe Polese}\\[.3cm] 
\end{flushleft}
\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vfill}

\preauthor{\begin{flushright}Autore Tesi:\\\bfseries} 
\postauthor{\end{flushright}}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code isn't compilable and there's no image

Comment: Thank you Christian i were just editing it, i have some connection issues, but thank you for your help anyway. :)

Comment: Yes, but we still can't compile it -- we don't have `structure.tex`

Comment: I wonder if the original file has a license?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Don't be silly. `structure.tex` directly leads to l-templates.com ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ah, the orange book?

Comment: Have alook at [how to write two sentences in the same line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313010) and [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)/ and don't bother with the complicated construction of the template.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll follow the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all kinds of stuff, for example forget about all the hooks and do the following.

```
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}\\[.5cm] 
    \institution\\ 
    \emph{\department}\\[.2cm] 
    Laurea Magistrale in Tecnologie Informatiche e Management 
    \par
    \hrulefill
\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{\vfill}
\author{\parbox{\textwidth}{Relatore:\hfill Autore:\\\textbf{Professor}\hfill\textbf{Student}}}
```

[image: texsxMemoirTemplateTitlepage]

---

Though i would set up my titlepage completely by hand, as seen in [How to customize my titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage)